# HMMlearn: How to use predict_proba function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I am trying to use the [predict_proba()](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) function on my HMM, but I get an error which i do not fully understand. First of all I create my model as follows:

```
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=vocab_size, covariance_type="full")
model.start_prob_ = np.array(frequency_list)
model.transmat_ = np.array(transitions)

integer_array = integer_array.reshape(-1,1)
model.fit(integer_array)
```

With integer_list being my list of integers which is my training data. 
If I then try to run the predict_proba function as follows, I get the following error:

```
base._BaseHMM.predict_proba(integer_array, None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-62c5bedf3e8a> in <module>
----> 1 base._BaseHMM.predict_proba(integer_list, None)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\hmmlearn\base.py in predict_proba(self, X, lengths)
    390             State-membership probabilities for each sample from ``X``.
    391         """
--> 392         _, posteriors = self.score_samples(X, lengths)
    393         return posteriors
    394 

AttributeError: 'np.array' object has no attribute 'score_samples'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I already tried to convert my array to a list, but that gives a similar error.

Comment: Can you show completely code?

Comment: what parts of the code would you like to see?
the integer list looks as follows: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9, 10, 11, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 16, 8, 18, 19, 20, 21, 6, 6, 22, 4, 23, 8, 24, 25, 2, 26, 27, 5, 19, 7, 4, 10]

Comment: Nevermind I fixed the issue, I should have used model.predict_proba() , thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The call should be

```
model.predict_proba(integer_array, None)
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
base._BaseHMM.predict_proba(model, integer_array, None)
```

Note model being passed as `self` parameter.